# How to create event for UIButton in ViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I add a `UIButton` programmatically, and I want to call a method when pressing on it, I'm not sure how to design such a pattern:

1. where should I put event handler, or action method? in view controller or view itself.
2. If I put the method in view controller, how can I manipulate the `SubViews` of the View in the method? should I expose all of `SubViews` (`UIButton`, etc.) to controller by putting them in view's header file as properties? Actually this question shall be asked in this way: How can I implement by code that `SubViews` in a view are associated to an `IBOutlet` properties by Interface Builder...

Comment: the property can be accessed by all subviews in a view controller. You can create an ibaction outlet to handle button event or add your own target method!!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check this link for the basics of iOS view hierarchy:
[Getting started with iOS Views](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/getting-started-with-ios-views-and-view-controllers-part-1/) and understand the following diagram (credits: techrepublic.com):

[image: Credits: http://www.techrepublic.com/]

Programmatically:

```
// Create your button wherever you wish (below is example button)
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320, 450);
[myButton setTitle:@"Yay" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didTouchUp:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:myButton];

// This method will be called when touch up is made on the button
- (void)didTouchUp:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSLog(@"Button Pressed!");
}
```

Explanation:

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didTouchUp:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

- **myButton** - your button view
- **addTarget** - the target in which the method exist in
- **action** - the selector you want to call
- **forControlEvents** - control event the user will do to trigger this action

Using Storyboards:

[image]

- (A) Make sure the storyboard is corresponding to the correct class
- (B) Drag UIButton from the object library into the storyboard

Then add to the ViewController.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;

- (IBAction)didTouchUp:(id)sender;

@end
```

Then add to the ViewController.m file:

```
- (IBAction)didTouchUp:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Button Pressed!");
}
```

Lastly, create the connection between the UIButton and the IBAction:

[image]

- (A) Right click on the button view
- (B) Drag touch up action to the button view on the storyboard
- (C) Press on didTouchUp:

This is the very basic flow to do such a step... you might want to expend your skills by reading the following:

- [Storyboard vs IB vs Code](http://www.toptal.com/ios/ios-user-interfaces-storyboards-vs-nibs-vs-custom-code)
- [Stanford University Developing iOS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZqKbN_C4Yvg)

Comment: @AlanHoo my pleasure! If it helped you, please mark my answer as the correct one. Big thanks!